# jQuery Cycle Plugin is throwing error: "has no method 'cycle'"

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to implement the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) on a project, but it's throwing the following error (and failing to initialize):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle'
```

I'm using jQuery version `1.8.0` and the plugin is version  `2.9999.6`.

I'm done a bit of Googling around, but I can't see many references to this error and the ones I have found don't seem to be relevant. Any nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be using `src=` instead of `type=` in your `<script>` tag:

```
<!-- Add Cycle Plugin -->
<script src="js/plugins/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can load the script with jQuery if you want it to be non-blocking:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('js/plugins/jquery.cycle.all.js', function(){
        $('.feature').cycle({ fx: 'fade' }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No luck :( Put it right below `modernizr` in the `head` with no change.

Comment: For giggles, I tried moving jquery up above the cycle plugin in the head and still nothing.

Comment: Doh! you have `type=` instead of `src=` in your `<script>` tag that is loading `jQuery.cycle()`

Comment: I like that `getScript` option though. I'd never seen that used.

Comment: It's a nice option for dynamically loading scripts when they are needed instead of all the time... it just happened to fix the problem because of the missing src attribute though :)

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could mark this as the correct answer when you get a chance, thanks!

Comment: You got it. Sorry, got sidetracked.